# Why does the prop disable cause the button in a rails form to not fire?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Ok so i have this form

```
  = form_tag 'some_controller/create', :remote => true do
  ...
  ...
  .right= submit_tag 'Submit Me', :id => 'submit_me'
  .clear
```

here is my create.js.erb

```
  $('#submit_me').remove();
```

and my application.js file

```
$('#submit_me').live('click', function(){
  $(this).val("One moment please...");
  $(this).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

The problem is that when i click it the form doesnt submit. If i take out the `$(this).prop("disabled", true);`

then it submits fine and everything works well but that doesnt make sense as to why I cant disable the button...any suggestions

Comment: It works that way because the default behavior of the button happens *after* your event handler is run. If at that point the button is disabled, the form isn't submitted.

Comment: @Pointy, exactly! But to my surprise, IE seems to submit the form while Chrome & Firefox don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should handle the more appropriate event here, which is `submit` in this case. Plus, [don't use `.live()`](http://liveisdeprecated.com/)

```
$('#Parent').on('submit', '#theForm',function(){
  $('#submit_me').val("One moment please...");
  $('#submit_me').prop("disabled", true);
});
```

A couple of notes here:

- If you don't know the `'#Parent'` for sure, you can use `'body'`.
- `click` DOES work, but you have to manually submit the form by doing `$('#theForm').submit()`

Comment: +1 for LiveIsDeprecated page. I can only imagine the level of anger on a page about IE6 :)